# How to display a link in the footer section

Tags: plugins, hooks, footer

i'm using the BAAP Mobile version plugin and the footer link that switches between desktop and mobile version is being displayed outside of the wrapper>footer divs. Is there a hook or a method to have the switcher link display in the footer section?

This is the function that creates and displays the links in the wpmp_switcher.php file.

```
function wpmp_switcher_wp_footer($force=false) {
  if(!$force && (get_option('wpmp_switcher_mode')=='none' || get_option('wpmp_switcher_footer_links')!='true')) {
    return;
  }
  switch (wpmp_switcher_outcome()) {
    case WPMP_SWITCHER_MOBILE_PAGE:
      print wpmp_switcher_link('desktop', __('Switch 2 our desktop site', 'wpmp'));
      break;
    case WPMP_SWITCHER_DESKTOP_PAGE:
      print "<p>" . wpmp_switcher_link('mobile', __('Switch to our mobile site', 'wpmp')) . "</p>";
      break;
  }
}
```

Comment: You don't need a hook, just call `wpmp_switcher_wp_footer` function in tthe right place.

Comment: But the above code displays the link by itself, and if the function is called, then it would display links in both footer and at the end of the wrapper tags. so what would be the right way to have the link show up only in the footer section?

Comment: Got it.. I had to comment out this line of code add_action('wp_footer', 'wpmp_switcher_wp_footer');

Comment: commenting out the code will be bad because next plugin update its back , better use `remove_action`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look in the plugin's directory `plugins/wpmp_switcher/wpmp_switcher.php`  on line 53 you will see this:

```
add_action('wp_footer', 'wpmp_switcher_wp_footer');
```

so you can either remove this action and call it in your theme your self with:

```
remove_action('wp_footer', 'wpmp_switcher_wp_footer');
```

or you just make sure that `wp_footer();` is inside your wrapper>footer divs.

Comment: Yep got it. Seems pretty simple now that i've done it :) Thanks

Comment: Glad you got it.